# How to pass a class member function that modifies class members to a function that takes a function pointer

Tags: c++, arduino, callback

I am writing software for an Arduino-powered weather station.

I have a class for each of the sensor systems (some simple, some complex) and the rain gauge one needs to use the Arduino `attachInterrupt` function.
Signature:

```cpp
void attachInterrupt(uint8_t interruptNum, void (*userFunc)(), int mode)
```

This is used to execute a callback when a pin changes state, which increment a counter (which is a member variable of the class).

I currently have the following:

```cpp
// `pulses` and `pin` are member variables.
void RainGauge::begin()
{
  pulses = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), callback, FALLING);
}
```

I need to somehow define that callback.

I have tried this, without success, due to the capturing aspect:

```cpp
void RainGauge::begin()
{
  pulses = 0;
  auto callback = [this](void) {
    pulses++;
  };
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), callback, FALLING);
}
```

This gives the error `no suitable conversion function from "lambda []()->void" to "void (*)()" existsC/C++(413)`.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Neither a non-static member function, nor a lambda, are type-equivalent to `void (*)()`, a basic pointer to function returning `void` with no arguments. And the latter says as much with the reported error. In short, you can't get there unless you can somehow map an argumentless function to an object instance. Typically this is done with a user-defined optional pointer argument your provide at registration time, that is conveyed back as an argument to the callback. However, attachInterrupt doens't support that. A mapping strategy is probably your most-basic , non-trivial option.

Comment: You need to use a standalone C-style function (not a member, not a lambda, not a `std::function`, just plain old function), and pass data to it via a global variable (of type `RainGauge` or `RainGauge*` probably). Not pretty, but that's an interrupt handler. This is the way hardware usually works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, on what object should the function be invoked when the interrupt occurs?

You could do it this way for example:

```
class RainGauge {
  int pulses;
public:
  void begin(int pin, void (*callback)());
  void increment();
};

void RainGauge::begin(int pin, void (*callback)())
{
  pulses = 0;
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pin), callback, FALLING);
}

void RainGauge::increment()
{
  pulses++;
}

RainGauge RainGauge1;
RainGauge RainGauge2;

void setup() {
  RainGauge1.begin(2, []() {RainGauge1.increment();});
  RainGauge2.begin(3, []() {RainGauge2.increment();});
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Juraj. I was expecting to have to do something like this, based on previous dealings with this type of issue, but wasn't sure how to do it in this instance (typing, etc.).

Comment: Except... it won't work. `[]() {RainGauge1.increment()}` isn't valid C++ (you're missing a semi-colon after `()`, and your lambda is no more viable as a `void (*)()` then the OP's `callback` lambda was. So I have no idea how this saw fruition as a solution. Maybe Arduino likes to bend/break C++ language rules more than I'm familiar, but I seriously doubt so for something like this. No lambda, non-static member, or otherwise, is type-compatible with `void(*)()`, no matter how hard you wish otherwise.

Comment: @WhozCraig. thank you for the comment. it is gcc. there was a warning about the `;`, which I missed. I fixed it in the answer now. static members work too https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/89173/attach-the-arduino-isr-function-to-the-class-member/89176#89176

Comment: The link you showed is *exactly* how one could do it correctly (thus, why I said "No lambda, **non-static member**, or otherwise") will work.  The other option, using a mapping strategy, is what the Gammon's article doc refers to a "Glue" routines. They effectively map to an object instance using a static map *and* a static callback as an intermediary.

Comment: @WhozCraig, there 'glue' routines are static members there